# Axios Interceptor doesn't set Token to the Authorization Header

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, axios

In my React Native app, I use Axios Interceptors to set an Auth header Token on every request. Everything works correctly but when I log out and clear the stored token (By PURGING the Redux store) and log in again, the new token doesn't get set on the Axios Authorization Header (Gets empty).

This is how I'm setting the Auth header on Axios with Interceptors:

```
const App = () => {
  const token = useSelector(selectToken); // Token state
  const isLoggedOut = useSelector(selectIsLoggedOutState); // User logout state

  // Show logout message and purge the store
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoggedOut) {
      Toast.show({
        type: 'success',
        text1: logoutMessage,
      });

      persistor.purge();
    }
  }, [isLoggedOut]);

  // Intercept on request
  api.interceptors.request.use(
    config => {
      // Set authorization header
      if (token) {
        config.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
      }
      return config;
    },
    err => {
      return Promise.reject(err);
    },
  );

  // REST OF THE CODE
}
```

The most weird thing is that the header Token gets changed even if `token` is false in the `if block`, as if it doesn't even get checked.

I'd really appreciate any answer that might help me fix this weird problem.

Comment: Are you possibly adding multiple interceptors? Honestly, this stuff is best managed outside react and redux. Keep the axios instance and all the interceptors in a separate module. Put the token in a let variable inside that module, expose a setter function and call it when the token needs to change. Yes, you would have another place for state management this way, but it's isolated (axios instance only) and dedicated. React+redux only care about `isLoggedOut`, the actual token matters only to your one axios instance.